# Drupal view filter between two dates on published date

Tags: views, datetime, emails

I have a problem with view and filter on published date. In the view i display all my contacts with their published date. **It's the published date of the contact not a field date in entity contact**. it's look like that :

```
toto | 20/02/2015
titi | 23/02/2015
tutu | 27/02/2015
```

I tried to make a filter on the published date with start date and end date but i can't use it.

How can i make a filter between two date on published date ?

Thanks

Comment: You mean the post date of the node? You can choose post date as filter and then choose operator "between" and enter start and end date.

Comment: i know that i can choose between but when i choose it and i can't enter a start date and end date.. We can't use filter between on post date. I just had min and max..

Comment: you can do that by adding two published_date filters to post one is greater and the other is less with default values, if I did understood your question correctly?

Comment: @m.khamash, sounds about right, maybe write that as an answer?